# How to post webhook to a url on my local machine using ngrok?

Tags: localhost, webhooks, ngrok

I have ngrok setup on my local machine via port 8888 and is working fine

I can see the webhooks coming in from the source (Postmark) at localhost:4040/http/in

I want the webhook posted to localhost:8888/my_app/my_web_app_url so that I can test the JSON that I receive

How do I do this?

I have searched around and read the ngrok documentation, but not been able to find a solution I can understand

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Wow it's been 2 years :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want requests to be forwarded to localhost:8888/my_app/my_web_app_url, then wherever you are specifying the call-back for your service (Postmark in your case), set it as http://xxxxx.ngrok.io/my_app/my_web_app_url.